# Google Sheets script which opens the last modified sheet in a multiple sheet document

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a multiple sheet document. A sheet for every week of the year. The sheets are named W1->W53 Upon opening of the document, I’d prefer a sheet “in the neighborhood of” the current week is opened. If google sheets can detect the last modified cell, and opens the referring sheet, the sheet I am looking for would be opened most of the time.

Can somebody please help me?

I tried this script, but it doens't work

```js
function onOpen() {
  var lastModifiedSheet = UserProperties.getProperty("mySheetName");
  var lastModifiedCell  = UserProperties.getProperty("myCell");
  
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheetByName(lastModifiedSheet).getRange(lastModifiedCell).activate();
}
```

Comment: How is your Spreadsheet set up? Is the first sheet week 1, second sheet week 2, etc?

Comment: No, it is not. It starts with an overview tab, and it has a mid season tab in between.

Comment: Are the sheets named relevantly? (Week1, Week2, Week3 for example) I think it might be easier to open the respective tab using an onOpen() trigger

Comment: Your updated `onOpen()` won't work if you're not setting the Property `onEdit()`

Comment: Thank you. Any tips on how this onEdit() property can be set? I must say I am a real novice in this field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answer:

*You can use the `onEdit()` trigger to set properties, and then retrieve them using the `onOpen()` trigger.*

#### More Informtaion

Modifying the code you already have provided:

```js
function onEdit(e)  {
  var lms = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()
    .getProperty("lastModifiedSheet");
  var lmc = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()
    .getProperty("lastModifiedCell");

  if (lms == e.range.getSheet().getName() && lmc == e.range.getA1Notation()) {
    return;
  }
  else {
    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()
      .setProperty("lastModifiedSheet", e.range.getSheet().getName());

    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()
      .setProperty("lastModifiedCell", e.range.getA1Notation());
  }  
}
```

Then `onOpen()`:

```js
function onOpen() {
  var lastModifiedSheet = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()
    .getProperty("lastModifiedSheet");
  var lastModifiedCell = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()
    .getProperty("lastModifiedCell");

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(lastModifiedSheet)
    .getRange(lastModifiedCell).activate();
}
```

Rundown of this script:

- Each time the sheet is edited, the Sheet name and cell are saved to the properties
- Each time the sheet is opened, it reads the Sheet name and cell from properties and activates that cell

#### References:

- [Class PropertiesService | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service)
- [Simple Triggers - `onEdit(e)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite)
- [Simple Triggers - `onOpen(e)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onopene)